# Aggregate Sum of values based on multiple date ranges - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I am trying to determine the effect of adding an extra load to a power panel based on the panels state in time during the life cycle of a construction project. The power panel can have many loads (up to 240) associated with it and these loads can be installed or de-installed based on a construction schedule at any given time. The sum of load on the panel fluctuates over the life cycle of the project. Just because the load is at 90% today, doesn't automatically mean you have 10% available as a new load could be scheduled to be installed tomorrow. The project life cycle always has to be considered.

I need a query that will determine the maximum load of the panel at a given date based on the install/de-install dates of all loads on the panel.

Here is a sample view of the loads and their install/de-install dates.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp(
   PanelID     INTEGER  NOT NULL 
  ,LOADID      INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Load        VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
  ,kVA         NUMERIC(5,2) NOT NULL
  ,InstallDate DATE  NOT NULL
  ,DemoDate    DATE 
);
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,46706,'AUTO26',43.95,'07/07/1905','27/10/2016');
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,46706,'AUTO26',43.95,'07/07/1905','27/10/2016');
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,15539,'AUTO22',43.95,'01/01/2015',NULL);
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,20188,'OVEN101',46.47,'29/06/2017',NULL);
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,20186,'OVEN101',63.05,'29/06/2017',NULL);
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,46705,'AUTO28',61.25,'07/07/1905','27/10/2016');
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,20186,'OVEN101',63.05,'29/06/2017',NULL);
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,46705,'AUTO28',61.25,'07/07/1905','27/10/2016');
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,15539,'AUTO22',43.95,'01/01/2015',NULL);
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,20188,'OVEN101',46.47,'29/06/2017',NULL);
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,15538,'AUTO22',66.65,'01/01/2015',NULL);
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,20187,'OVEN101',50.44,'29/06/2017',NULL);
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,46704,'AUTO26',61.25,'07/07/1905','27/10/2016');
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,46707,'AUTO28',43.95,'07/07/1905','27/09/2016');
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,15538,'AUTO22',66.65,'01/01/2015',NULL);
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,20187,'OVEN101',50.44,'29/06/2017',NULL);
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,46704,'AUTO26',61.25,'07/07/1905','27/10/2016');
INSERT INTO #temp(PanelID,LOADID,Load,kVA,InstallDate,DemoDate) VALUES (1380,46707,'AUTO28',43.95,'07/07/1905','27/09/2016');
```

My solution to date has been to use a cursor to find the load (Sum or kVA) of the panel at every given date associated with the loads on the panel. As there can be up to 240 loads on the panel, this is resulting in a major performance hit.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Edit: I have simplified the create table as recommended. You only have to group by the Panel and sum the kVA column to retrieve the result. However, I want it based on the install dates of each Load on the panel. If the de-install date is less than the install date, it should not appear in the aggregate function.

Comment: Your example code does not run. It is giving a primary key violation. There are multiple 1375 SourceIDs when they need to be unique.

Comment: I think you need to do 2 thing with your question to get a better response. The temp table creation approach is good, but look at the fields, do you need them all to represent the problem and do you need all of those rows? So simplify the sample data to the minimum requirement and then supply what you expect the output to look like. Also, your current attempt would be useful.

Comment: Also, i'm in the UK, so get: *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.*, best to format your dates like `yyyymmdd`, sql will always understand this.

Comment: Adding `SET DATEFORMAT dmy;` to the start helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I will keep this in mind next time.

Comment: I'd need an example really - when does it become de-installed?  If I have a sourceID, how do I know when it was added then removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that DemoDate is the date a load is removed from a board and null means they are not removed. Here is a common table expression query that should give the maximum kVA over the duration:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;

CREATE TABLE #temp(
     SourceID       INTEGER        NOT NULL
    ,PanelID        INTEGER        NOT NULL
    ,BP_DP          INTEGER        NOT NULL
    ,depth          BIT            NOT NULL
    ,LOADID         INTEGER        NOT NULL
    ,Load           VARCHAR(7)     NOT NULL
    ,kVA            NUMERIC(5,2)   NOT NULL
    ,InstallDate    DATE           NOT NULL
    ,DemoDate       DATE
);

INSERT INTO #temp
    (SourceID, PanelID, BP_DP, depth, LOADID, Load,      kVA,   InstallDate,  DemoDate    )
VALUES
    (1375,     1380,    2,     1,     46706,  'AUTO26',  43.95, '07/07/1905', '27/10/2016'),
    (1380,     1380,    2,     0,     46706,  'AUTO26',  43.95, '07/07/1905', '27/10/2016'),
    (1375,     1380,    2,     1,     15539,  'AUTO22',  43.95, '01/01/2015', NULL        ),
    (1375,     1380,    2,     1,     20188,  'OVEN101', 46.47, '29/06/2017', NULL        ),
    (1380,     1380,    2,     0,     20186,  'OVEN101', 63.05, '29/06/2017', NULL        ),
    (1380,     1380,    2,     0,     46705,  'AUTO28',  61.25, '07/07/1905', '27/10/2016'),
    (1375,     1380,    2,     1,     20186,  'OVEN101', 63.05, '29/06/2017', NULL        ),
    (1375,     1380,    2,     1,     46705,  'AUTO28',  61.25, '07/07/1905', '27/10/2016'),
    (1380,     1380,    2,     0,     15539,  'AUTO22',  43.95, '01/01/2015', NULL        ),
    (1380,     1380,    2,     0,     20188,  'OVEN101', 46.47, '29/06/2017', NULL        ),
    (1375,     1380,    2,     1,     15538,  'AUTO22',  66.65, '01/01/2015', NULL        ),
    (1375,     1380,    2,     1,     20187,  'OVEN101', 50.44, '29/06/2017', NULL        ),
    (1375,     1380,    2,     1,     46704,  'AUTO26',  61.25, '07/07/1905', '27/10/2016'),
    (1375,     1380,    2,     1,     46707,  'AUTO28',  43.95, '07/07/1905', '27/10/2016'),
    (1380,     1380,    2,     0,     15538,  'AUTO22',  66.65, '01/01/2015', NULL        ),
    (1380,     1380,    2,     0,     20187,  'OVEN101', 50.44, '29/06/2017', NULL        ),
    (1380,     1380,    2,     0,     46704,  'AUTO26',  61.25, '07/07/1905', '27/10/2016'),
    (1380,     1380,    2,     0,     46707,  'AUTO28',  43.95, '07/07/1905', '27/10/2016');   

WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT 
        t1.PanelID,
        t1.InstallDate,
        SUM(t2.kVA) LoadAferInstall
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT
            PanelID,
            InstallDate
        FROM
            #Temp
        ) t1
        JOIN #Temp t2
            ON t1.PanelID = t2.PanelID
            AND t2.InstallDate <= t1.InstallDate
            AND (t2.DemoDate IS NULL OR t2.DemoDate >= t1.InstallDate)
    GROUP BY
        t1.PanelID, t1.InstallDate
)
SELECT
    PanelID,
    MAX(LoadAferInstall) MaxPanelLoad_kVA
FROM
    cte
GROUP BY
    PanelID
;

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: This is almost correct. However, it seems to be duplicating the rows before summing the results. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your assumptions are accurate. However, If I remove the last aggregate and check load total for 1905-07-07, it is summing to 3360. it should be 961. In thoughts?

Comment: I have updated the example to remove the duplicates. However I'm not sure where you are getting 961 from? 1905-07-07 is the first date and as such the total load on this day should just be the sum of all the rows with that InstallDate? This total is 420.80.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks